# Jest unit test issue: "module not found"

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, ts-jest

Currently Jest is failing the tests because it cannot find the module called inside a component:

```sh
 FAIL  tests/Unit/VHeaderBar.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@@/public/assets/images/placeholder.png' from 'VHeaderBar.vue'



      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at src/components/VHeaderBar.vue:687:18
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/VHeaderBar.vue:749:3)
```

## Case

In **NuxtJs** the `@@` signs refer to the *root* directory, because in the end solution we want to store images in the public folder or storage folder, which is located in the root of the project.

When running tests **jest** checks the `src` folder, then tries to mount the images stored from the root and can't find them.

I have tried many different ways to fix this issue, but can't seem to find the solution.
Here's a shortlist of what I already tried:

- Changing `regex` to check for image files and lead it to the correct folder using the `moduleNameMapper` option in the Jest config file.
- I read something on Stack about using a "mock" folder that exports the images files through javascript, but that didn't work.
- Using the `modulePaths` option in the Jest config file.
- Creating an alias in the `tsconfig.js` for the *assets* folder and using that in the `moduleNameMapper`
- Tried a different approach in the VueJS component and test file to load assets, which broke the compiling process (so I reverted that).

### Current Jest Config file

```js
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "vue",
        "js",
        "json"
    ],
    watchman: false,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i": "<rootDir>/public/assets/images/$1",
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "^~~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    transform: {
        // process js with `babel-jest`
        "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        // process `*.vue` files with `vue-jest`
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
        // process `*.ts` files with `ts-jest`
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest",
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "<rootDir>/src/components/**/*.vue",
        "<rootDir>/src/pages/**/*.vue",
        "<rootDir>/src/layouts/**/*.vue"
    ],
    testMatch: [
        '**/tests/Unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
}
```

### Current folder structure (only folders we use for the test)

```
project folder
- public
-- assets
--- **images**

- src
-- components
--- **mounted component** (works)

- tests
-- Unit
--- mountedComponent.spec.ts
```

Any suggestions?

Do I fix the `jest.config`?

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Do I have to fix the `tsconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and it goes down to typescript not being able to import that file.

I've solved it by adding file type definition to `files.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "*.pdf" {
  const file: Buffer;
  export default file;
}

declare module "*.jpeg" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Referring to this file in `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* ... */
  },
  "files": ["./src/@types/files.d.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And adding file transforms to `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src/"],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "@lib/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/lib/$1",
  },
  transform: { // Transforms here
    "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "@jagi/jest-transform-graphql",
    "\\.(html|html|txt|pem|key)$": "./jest-transform-text.js",
    "\\.(p12|pdf|otf|ttf)$": "./jest-transform-buffer.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"

  },
  coverageReporters: ["text", "lcov"],
};
```

Examples of transform files:

```js
// jest-transform-buffer.js

"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(filename, "hex");
    return (
      'module.exports=Buffer.from("' +
      data +
      '","hex");module.exports.default=module.exports;'
    );
  },
};
```

And for images (or other files where you only need a filename) from create react app:

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const camelcase = require('camelcase');

// This is a custom Jest transformer turning file imports into filenames.
// http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    const assetFilename = JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename));

    if (filename.match(/\.svg$/)) {
      // Based on how SVGR generates a component name:
      // https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr/blob/01b194cf967347d43d4cbe6b434404731b87cf27/packages/core/src/state.js#L6
      const pascalCaseFilename = camelcase(path.parse(filename).name, {
        pascalCase: true,
      });
      const componentName = `Svg${pascalCaseFilename}`;
      return `const React = require('react');
      module.exports = {
        __esModule: true,
        default: ${assetFilename},
        ReactComponent: React.forwardRef(function ${componentName}(props, ref) {
          return {
            $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
            type: 'svg',
            ref: ref,
            key: null,
            props: Object.assign({}, props, {
              children: ${assetFilename}
            })
          };
        }),
      };`;
    }

    return `module.exports = ${assetFilename};`;
  },
};
```